# how remove tag html when show text(froala editor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

iam use editor froala when insert text then show text iam see tag html in text

plese see text

```
 <B><p class="fr-tag">test   
 testttt  good<br></p></B>
```

iam use this code for show and remove tag

```
<dd>
        @{
           @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FTxtnews)
        }

    </dd>
var val = $('textarea').val();
val = val.replace("</p><p class="fr-tag">", '<p class="clear">');
```

edit:
iam sloved this problem with use  **@Html.Raw**

Answer (score 0):

try assigning your HTML string to an element and get text of it by removing all child elements like this,

```
var dummyString = '<B><p class="fr-tag">test testttt  good<br></p></B>';
$('#dummyDiv').html(dummyString);

var val = $("#dummyDiv")
    .clone()    //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()  //again go back to selected element
    .text();
```

Have a DIV in your page (possibly hide it) with id '`dummyDiv`'.
Hope it works. Thank you.